# extra } when use titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, errors, titlesec

In the `.tex` file, I want to use the package `titlesec`. But there is a error:

```
! Argument of \subparagraph has an extra }.
```

Is there some simple method to fix this?

The code is:

```
\documentclass{llncs}    
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: The `llncs` class is used for submissions to Springer; it's not a good idea to change the setup. In any case, the class explicitly disables `\subparagraph`: “You should not use `\subparagraph` with this class” is what appears when you try using it under normal setting.

Comment: Please let us know if you got the answer figured out for this.

Answer (score 24):

The `titlesec` package assumes that the usual sectioning levels are defined with the standard method, basically

```
\def\section{\@startsection...}
```

However, the `llncs` class defines `\subparagraph` to produce a warning text that the command should not be used.

If you really want to change the appearance of section titles, ignoring the fact that you probably are using `llncs` for submissions to Springer, where the changes will quite surely be overridden, you can do in the following way:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

%% Save the class definition of \subparagraph
\let\llncssubparagraph\subparagraph
%% Provide a definition to \subparagraph to keep titlesec happy
\let\subparagraph\paragraph
%% Load titlesec
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%% Revert \subparagraph to the llncs definition
\let\subparagraph\llncssubparagraph
```

This will produce no error when loading `titlesec`.

Comment: God, is this you?

Answer (score 1):

You can comment out the lines that have `\subparagraph` in `titlesec.sty`. I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about but it compiles fine for this way.

Comment: Please have a look to the comment of @egreg. BTW: It is not a good choice to change a package file like `titlesec.sty`. If a change is needed, copy the file, rename it to `mytitlesec.sty` for example and change this one. Now you can use your changed package using `\usepackage{mytitlesec.sty}` without any bad effects to other documents using the original `titlesec.sty`.