# Spacing below section title

Tags: spacing, sectioning

The document class `acm_proc_article-sp` seems to be incompatible with the package `titlesec`. At least I can not load it. It fails with

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \subparagraph 

l.1470 \ttl@extract\subparagraph
```

However, the space below section titles is too little. The text attached directly. How can I automatically insert some space? (Instead of a manual `\vspace`)

Comment: Fixed a typo. `-mod` is an exact copy of the original.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the class for a submission, then you shouldn't modify its behavior: the editors of the journal or conference proceedings won't be happy.

In any case, the problem is similar to the one described in [extra } when use titlesec package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103020/extra-when-use-titlesec-package) because the `acm_proc_article-sp` class doesn't define `\subparagraph`.

You should be able to get around the problem by adding a mock definition of `\subparagraph` by copying it from `article.cls` before loading `titlesec`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subparagraph{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}
  {\parindent}
  {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}
  {-1em}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{titlesec}
\let\subparagraph\relax % You don't want to use \subparagraph
```

Comment: Thank you! However you are probably right about not changing the behaviour.