# Adding a period after section

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

which moves the text up after the section (and subsection). How can I add a period after the section title so that I get:

2.3 Section title. Text of paragraph...

Comment: This is covered in the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) using two different approaches. See section **4.4. Putting a Dot after the Section Title** (p 12) with `\periodafter` and a similar approach using the `explicit` package option (section **3.7. Other Package Options**, p 8).

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the comment. I will take a look at this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two ways.

The last argument of `\titleformat` can contain a macro that takes the title as its argument. So

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\addperiod}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {\addperiod}
\newcommand{\addperiod}[1]{#1.}
```

Alternatively, use the `explicit` option; in this case you have to use `#1` in the last argument to `\titleformat` to stand for the title.

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {#1.}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {#1.}
```

The first way is more customizable.

Comment: Thanks for this solution!
I first had some problems to get this working in combination with Springer `llcns` style. I also found this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103020/extra-when-use-titlesec-package
The combination of both solutions solved my problem.