# Latex sections, subsections without ending period

Tags: sectioning

How to remove an ending period in sections, subsections, ... numbering?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: These settings are typically set up by the document class. Can you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that highlights your problem?

Comment: The current MWE does not display the problem on my system. (**edit:** unless you mean the period after the number?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr9DQ.png)

Comment: Exactly I mean ending period in numbering, not after titles.

Comment: It is definitely something set by `\setdefaultlanguage{russion}`.  This can be overridden with `titlesec` or similar; you can probably adapt http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137194/17423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `\setdefaultlanguage{russian}` your example doesn't have these periods, so it is something set up by especially for Russian. I don't find an option to turn that off, but you can turn the special handling off "manually" with

```
\makeatletter
\def\russian@capsformat{}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.

Comment: It should probably be a feature request for Polyglossia.

Comment: @pst Yeah, I know I don't have such problems with English documents. Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Although pst's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168280/27635) removes the ending periods, it also changes the formatting of titles used by the Russian language.

If you want to keep the default spacing defined for Russian, you'd better add these lines in your preamble, so only the period is removed, but not the correct spacing.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\postchapter{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsection{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsubsection{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsubsubsection{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postparagraph{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsubparagraph{\hspace{0.5em}}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\postchapter{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsection{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsubsection{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsubsubsection{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postparagraph{\hspace{0.5em}}%
  \def\postsubparagraph{\hspace{0.5em}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]