# Adding period/dot after subsubsection title

Tags: koma-script, apa-style

Similar to [Adding a period after section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137193/adding-a-period-after-section) . But I'm using KOMA, so I can't use `titlesec`.

Going for APA Style Guide, FYI.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% --- APA Style --- %

% For spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Indent even the 1st paragraph after each section header.

\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-1em, indent=0.5in]{subsubsection}

% --- End of APA Style --- %

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{This should be centered}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{This is same as default for KOMA}

\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection[Runin, and need a dot after this title]{Runin, and need a dot after this title.}

Without resorting to using a separate `short title` without period at the end, and a `title` with the ending period, I hope to do just:

\subsubsection{Have dot at end}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If subsubsection are runin headers you have to redefine `\sectioncatchphraseformat` to insert a dot after the subsubsection title text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
% --- APA Style --- %
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-1em, indent=\the\parindent]{subsubsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{\centering}{}% center section titles
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4%
  \ifstr{#1}{subsubsection}{.}{}% dot after subsection titles
}
% --- End of APA Style --- %

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{This should be centered}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{This is same as default for KOMA}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Runin, and need a dot after this title}
Without resorting to using a separate `short title` without period at the end, and a `title` with the ending period, I hope to do just:
\subsubsection{Have dot at end}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}

\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\usepackage[usedvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{romanbar}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{}\textcolor{red}
]{chapter}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}
  {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
  {\ifstr{#1}{}{\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{chapter}{\protect\Romanbar{#1}}{#2}}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If all runin headings should get the dot at the end, use:

```
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{\hskip #2#3#4.}
```

**Additional remarks:**

Do not misuse the font element `section` to center the section headings. Redefine `\sectionlinesformat` instead.
There is no need to load package `indentfirst`.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me `\the\parindent` (and presumably everything `\the`). Why shouldn't I use `addtokomafont{section}`? Because that is intended to change fonts, rather than section elements? Why is there no need to load `indentfirst`? I need even the 1st paragraphs to be indented.

Comment: `\addtokomafont` and `\setkomafont` should be used only to change or set font attributes. If the first paragraph after a section heading should be intended, change `beforeskip` to "positive" values (as you can see in my example). The default values for `beforeskip` for each section level can be found in the documentation (see the explanations for `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution for everything other than `\subsubsection` (which you redeclare, that's why not working). The macro `\sectionlinesformat` will automatically append the dot.

You will find the documentation (scrguide/scrguien) of this macro in section 21 (page 508 in German guide, page 461 in English guide). It is one of the macros KOMA uses to customize sectioning (instead of titlesec's mechanisms).

[image: koma]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% --- APA Style --- %

% For spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Indent even the 1st paragraph after each section header.

\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-1em, indent=0.5in]{subsubsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip#2 #3}{#4.}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{This should be centered}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{This is same as default for KOMA}

\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection[Runin, and need a dot after this title]{Runin, and need a dot after this title.}

Without resorting to using a separate `short title` without period at the end, and a `title` with the ending period, I hope to do just:

\subsubsection{Have dot at end}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for adding answer (+1). i'm not familiar with `koma` bundle (i rather use `memoir`), so i learn something new. I suggest/ask you that you add to your answer, where in (huge) documentation we can find information about formatting of `\section{...}.   i already delete mine answer.

Comment: @Zarko Edited it in.

Comment: this information is well hidden in documentation. when i wrote my answer, i check manual (toc) and this didn't got me any clue, where to search :-(. this is pity ans serious drawback for package users.

Comment: @Zarko You pointed me to the `titlesec` equivalent that is `sectionlinesformat` (and likely helped @esdd 's answer). The documentation doesn't help with navigation. A "cookbook-like" organization would be better. Or at least try to match with well-known packages out there (eg `titlesec`). It is inspiring how the community (you et. al) work together to fix issues with incomplete organization of manuals. I'm gonna tag this with `titlesec` and `koma`, so others can find this.