# How to conditionally add a period after a section title when it is followed by normal text

Tags: koma-script, sections-paragraphs

As a follow up to [Adding period/dot after subsubsection title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415222/adding-period-dot-after-subsubsection-title), I need to find a way to conditionally add a period/dot after the subsection title when the title is directly followed by normal text. If it is followed by another heading or a float, there should be no period. In the example below, the title of Section 1.1 should not end in a period/dot because it is immediately followed by a subsection and not normal text.

Context: This is the strict style specification for an ANSI standard I am working on.

Can anyone help with this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% Body Section Definitions
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\sffamily\large,
  runin=false,
  beforeskip=10pt,
  afterskip=4pt,
  afterindent=false
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries,
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=10pt
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries,
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=10pt
]{subsubsection}

\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{\hskip #2#3#4.}

\begin{document}

\section{Level 1 headings never end in a period}

\subsection{Level 2 headings should only end in a period if they are immediately followed by normal text}

\subsubsection{Level 3 is the same as level 2}

This section begins with normal text content, and its heading should end in a period. But the previous section should not end in a period because it is followed by another heading.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: LaTeX is not very good at this kind of look-ahead functionality, basically a document is processed from top to bottom and content is put in the output document as soon as it is processed. Information from earlier in the document can be taken into account (because it is already seen) but information that comes later is not yet part of the processing. So here it would be the most practical solution to not use automatic periods and add them manually where needed. It is possible by storing information in the `.aux` file and reading it in future runs, but that would be rather complex.

Comment: I thought about adding the period manually (I could actually automate this through a pandoc filter since my original content is starting from Markdown), but I'd need a way to do that without impacting the section title that appears in the TOC, PDF bookmarks, and/or references to the section title elsewhere in the text.

If someone could help me with a more permanent solution utilizing the `.aux` file, I would welcome that too.

Comment: For the TOC and pdf bookmarks you can use the optional argument to `\section` etc., for example `\section[Title without period]{Title with period.}`. The optional (first) argument is used in the TOC and bookmarks, the mandatory (second) argument is used in the text. Depending on what you use to refer to the title in the document this would also work, for example `nameref` strips the period by default when printing a title reference.

Comment: @Marijn, you mentioned the `.aux` file solution as a "rather complex" option. Is it so complex that it is not worth describing here? I'm considering posting a bounty, but if it's complex beyond reasonable effort, I will likely just pursue the pre-process approach through Pandoc.

Comment: The more I think about it the trickier it becomes :) It is not just writing to and reading from the aux file, the problem is also to detect that normal text is there at all - you can hook into a macro like `\subsection` but you can't hook into normal text (although with LuaLaTeX it is a bit easier using a callback). So if you would post a bounty I probably will not try it - someone else might, though.

Comment: I started the bounty for you, I have a bit more reputation to spend after all.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: This is a different way of looking at the situation.  The ams document classes (`amsart`, etc.) by default insert a period at the end of a run-in section heading, and provide the command `\nopunct` to suppress it.  Originally created to get rid of a superfluous period when the heading ends with `?`, it would be applicable also for the situations you describe.  It's manual, but ...

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to look forward to detect, if a heading is followed by another heading. But with some heuristic you can detect, of a heading is preceded by another heading. In the following example, I use the skip at the end of heading to detect is at the next level heading. To do so I use the *do-hooks* of KOMA-Script explained at Part II of the user manual:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% Body Section Definitions
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\sffamily\large,
  runin=false,
  beforeskip=10pt,
  afterskip=4pt,
  afterindent=false
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries,
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=10pt
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries,
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=10pt
]{subsubsection}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\storesubsectiondot}[1]{%
  \ifdim\lastskip=4pt \else
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\global\string\@namedef{subsection\thesubsection dot}{.}}%
  \fi
}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/subsubsection}{%
  \storesubsectiondot
}
\newcommand*{\addsubsectiondot}{%
  \@nameuse{subsection\thesubsection dot}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\storesubsectiondot{}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{\hskip #2#3#4\Ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\addsubsectiondot}{.}}

\begin{document}

\section{Level 1 headings never end in a period}

\subsection{Level 2 headings should only end in a period if they are
  immediately followed by normal text}

Here we have normal text.

\subsubsection{Level 3 is the same as level 2}

This section begins with normal text content, and its heading should end in a
period. The previous section should also end in a period because it is
followed by normal text.

\section{Level 1 headings never end in a period}

\subsection{Level 2 headings should only end in a period if they are
  immediately followed by normal text}

\subsubsection{Level 3 is the same as level 2}

This section begins with normal text content, and its heading should end in a period. But the previous section should not end in a period because it is followed by another heading.

\section{Level 1 headings never end in a period}

\subsection{Level 2 headings should only end in a period if they are
  immediately followed by normal text}

This section begins with normal text content and therefore should have a dot.
\end{document}
```

The `\AtEndDocument` is used to also detect that the last heading is followed by text. Maybe this could be done less heuristic, because the last heading should always be followed by text. You should also be able to do similar for lower levels if needed.

But as you see, it is really complicated. So a more manual suggestion would be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% Body Section Definitions
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\sffamily\large,
  runin=false,
  beforeskip=10pt,
  afterskip=4pt,
  afterindent=false
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries,
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=10pt
]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries,
  runin=true,
  beforeskip=10pt
]{subsubsection}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sentencedot}{.}
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\RenewCommandCopy\sentencedot\relax}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Level 1 headings never end in a period}

\subsection{Level 2 headings should only end in a period if they are
  immediately followed by normal text\sentencedot}

Here we have normal text.

\subsubsection{Level 3 is the same as level 2\sentencedot}

This section begins with normal text content, and its heading should end in a
period. The previous section should also end in a period because it is
followed by normal text.

\section{Level 1 headings never end in a period}

\subsection{Level 2 headings should only end in a period if they are
  immediately followed by normal text}

\subsubsection{Level 3 is the same as level 2\sentencedot}

This section begins with normal text content, and its heading should end in a period. But the previous section should not end in a period because it is followed by another heading.

\section{Level 1 headings never end in a period}

\subsection{Level 2 headings should only end in a period if they are
  immediately followed by normal text\sentencedot}

This section begins with normal text content and therefore should have a dot.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Marijn what do you think of this solution?

Comment: @NealKruis I think it is clever to use `\lastskip` here, so it is worth the bounty. However, the solution is (currently) not very generalized, for example it does not work for subsubsections and it depends on setting and knowing the `afterskip` value. So, as cabohah also states, doing this manually (cf. through Pandoc) is probably the preferred solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Without a clean way to do this directly in LaTeX, I ended up writing a [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/) filter to automate this via [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/):

```python
import panflute as pf

HEADING_NAMES = [
  "chapter",
  "section",
  "subsection",
  "subsubsection",
  "paragraph",
  "subparagraph"]

def action(elem, doc):
  if isinstance(elem, pf.Header):
    if isinstance(elem.next, pf.Para):
      if elem.level > 1:
        before = inlatex(f"\\hypertarget{{{elem.identifier}}}{{%\n\\{HEADING_NAMES[elem.level]}[")
        middle = inlatex(r"]{")
        after = inlatex(fr".}}\label{{{elem.identifier}}}}}")
        return [pf.Plain(before, *elem.content, middle, *elem.content, after)]

def main(doc=None):
  return pf.run_filter(action, doc=doc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Note: This filter can be simplified once [this feature](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4409) is implemented.